# Loading a data frame with SparseDtype['string', pd.NA] from a pickle results in errors depending on the size of the data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pickle

I have been having some issues with pickling a data frame: what I observed is that the data frame after reading from pickle is not usable due to `StringArray requires a sequence of strings or pandas.NA`. Further tests resulted in me creating a smallish test case, but the interesting part is that the data frame needs to be of sufficient size for my problem to be reproducible.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create a data frame with 5 rows
df_small = pd.DataFrame(
    {'A': list(range(5)),
     'B': ['v1', 'v1', 'v1', 'v2', pd.NA],
     'C': [pd.NA, 'value2', 'value1', 'value1', 'value1']})

# create a data frame with 25000 rows
df_large = pd.DataFrame(
    {'A': list(range(5)) * 5000,
     'B': ['v1', 'v1', 'v1', 'v2', pd.NA] * 5000,
     'C': [pd.NA, 'value2', 'value1', 'value1', 'value1'] * 5000})

# assign type, notice that the SparseDtype is used
df_small = df_small.astype({'A': 'int32', 'B': pd.SparseDtype('string', pd.NA), 'C': 'string'})
df_large = df_large.astype({'A': 'int32', 'B': pd.SparseDtype('string', pd.NA), 'C': 'string'})

#store to disk
df_small.to_pickle('issue_small.pkl')
df_large.to_pickle('issue_large.pkl')

# load from disk
df_small1 = pd.read_pickle((open('issue_small.pkl', 'rb')))
df_large1 = pd.read_pickle((open('issue_large.pkl', 'rb')))

# this one will print OK
print(df_small1.C)

# this one will throw a ValueError
print(df_large1.C)
```

Almost anything that I could try to do with df_large1 will throw this error.

The problem goes away when the assignment of types is commented off. Unfortunately for me, most of columns I have are with under 1% density and the total data size is prohibitively large, so I am more or less stuck using sparse data objects.

Further, with or without using SparseDtype, `df_small.isna()` and `df_small1.isna()` show different results - as expected for the former, but all `False` for the latter.

Any ideas for what I could change to circumvent this behavior?

This is done on Python 3.8.1 and pandas 1.0.0 - downgrading is probably an option at this point..

Comment: I get the same error with non-sparse StringArray after pickling in Pandas 1.0.1.

Comment: same here for Pandas 1.0.2